# Trying to mock GPS tracker/ Traccar /Which Handler should I use to send Data to the particular port

Tags: java, jboss, netty, serversocket

> I'm trying to send the GPS data to the server port where the specific
>   protocol is been listened.

**AdmProtocolTester.java**

```
package MockTracker.TrackerSimulator;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
 import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
 import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer;
import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;

public class AdmProtocolDecoderTesterOne {  
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception{
        new AdmProtocolDecoderTesterOne("localhost", 5092).run();

    }
    private final String host;
    private final int port;

    public AdmProtocolDecoderTesterOne(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() throws Exception{
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try{
            Bootstrap clientBootstrap = new Bootstrap();

            clientBootstrap.group(group);
            clientBootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
            clientBootstrap.remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5092));
            clientBootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ClientHandler());
                }
            });
            ChannelFuture channelFuture = (ChannelFuture) clientBootstrap.connect().sync();
            channelFuture.getChannel().getCloseFuture().sync();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            while(true) {
                ((Channel) channelFuture).write(in.readLine()+ "\r\n");
                ((Channel) channelFuture).flush();
             }

        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        }

    }
}
```

***ClientHandler.java***

```
package MockTracker.TrackerSimulator;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import com.cloudhopper.commons.charset.CharsetUtil;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;

public class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteOrder> {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext){
        channelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Netty Rocks!", (Charset) CharsetUtil.CHARSET_UTF_8));
    }
    @Override
    protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteOrder msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(msg);        
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, Throwable cause){
        cause.printStackTrace();
        channelHandlerContext.close();
    }   
}
```

**ChannelInitializer Cannel.java**

```
package MockTracker.TrackerSimulator;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;

public class Channel  extends  ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>{

    clientBootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ChannelHandler());
        }
    });
}
```

**AdmProtocolTester.java**

**This is the actual data to be sent to the server port, instead of testing using Junit Test I'm trying to send the data using separate Java GPS Mocking Application.**

---

> public void testDecode() throws Exception {
>
> ```
>         AdmProtocolDecoder decoder = new AdmProtocolDecoder(new AdmProtocol());
>
>         verifyNull(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
>                 "010042033836313331313030323639343838320501000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000073"));
>
>         verifyPosition(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
>                 "01002680336510002062A34C423DCF8E42A50B1700005801140767E30F568F2534107D220000"));
>
>         verifyPosition(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
>                 "010022003300072020000000000000000044062A330000000000107F10565D4A8310"));
>
>         verifyPosition(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
>                 "0100268033641080207AA34C424CCF8E4239030800005B01140755E30F560000F00F70220000"));
>
>         verifyPosition(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
>                 "01002680336510002062A34C423DCF8E42A50B1700005801140767E30F568F2534107D220000"));
>
>         verifyPosition(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
>                 "01002200333508202000000000000000007F0D9F030000000000E39A1056E24A8210"));
>
>     }
>
> }
> ```

- [GPS tracker](https://github.com/tananaev/traccar)

  - [This is the link for the in-built Testing part](https://github.com/tananaev/traccar/tree/master/test/org/traccar/protocol)

**I'm trying to send the values through the console but I couldn't send it through the below line, could you please help me if i'm missing out anything**

---

> ((Channel) channelFuture).write(in.readLine()+ "\r\n");

Port **5092** is where **AdmProtocol** is listened by the server.